# openpyxl: AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

When i'm trying to fill the cell in existing .xlsx file and then save it to a new one I got message:

```
import openpyxl

path = "/home/karol/Dokumenty/wzor.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
new_protokol = sheet_obj


firma = input("Podaj nazwe: ")
nazwa_pliku = "Protokol odczytu"
filename = nazwa_pliku + firma + ".xlsx"



sheet_obj["C1"] = firma
sheet_obj["D1"] = input()

new_protokol.save(filename=filename)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karol/PycharmProjects/Protokolu/Main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sheet_obj["C1"] = firma
  File "/home/karol/PycharmProjects/Protokolu/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 309, in __setitem__
    self[key].value = value
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I think this may be relevant: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1228/unmerged-cells-are-still-considered-merged.  Which version of openpyxl are you using?

Comment: Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/ueWHnE6F

Comment: @Plato77 openpyxl-3.0.2

Answer (score 10):

When you merge cells all cells but the top-left one are removed from the worksheet. To carry the border-information of the merged cell, the **boundary cells** of the merged cell are created as MergeCells which always have the value `'None'`

```
ws.merge_cells('B2:F4')
top_left_cell = ws['B2']
top_left_cell.value = "My Cell"
```

Please try this approach, it'll work just fine for you.

Comment: This worked for me thanks

Comment: i already have values in it. not working

Answer (score 3):

To write in a merge cell, you must write in the cell in the upper left corner. And the error will not come out.

```
ws['I6']="123123123"
wb.save(filename=path....)
```

[image]

Comment: why just why??? why we need to do this. doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

I also met this error. I deleted my current Excel file and replaced it with a good Excel file, and then the error disappeared.