# Problem with openpyxl version 2.6.4 - 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using Python 3.7.9 & openpyxl 2.6.4. And I get this error: **AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only**

```
for merged in sheet.merged_cell_ranges: 
        if within_range(merged.bounds, cell):
            return sheet.cell(merged.min_row, merged.min_col).value
```

I cannot upgrade or downgrade the version. Somebody knows how I can solve it in a clean way?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Upgrade to openpyxl > 3

Comment: I cannot upgrade or downgrade the version. There are solutions for version 2.6.4?

Comment: There's a down-voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62461248/5386938) which says "To write in a merge cell, you must write in the cell in the upper left corner." I have no idea if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you Justin, I already read this solution but I cannot write in the upper left corner :)